# How can I pass dynamic component in a "renderToString" to convert into string

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jspdf, jspdf-autotable, render-to-string

This is what I mean by the dynamic component (the component which is getting data from the rest API)

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class WeatherData extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null,
    latitude: "19.970324",
    longitude: "79.303360",
    weatherData: {},
    _apiKey: "", //NOTE: In my code I have pass the Id here.
    city: "chandrapur,in"
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const { latitude, longitude, _apiKey, city } = this.state;
    axios
      .get(
        `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${_apiKey}`
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ weatherData: res.data }, () => {});
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.weatherData.weather &&
          this.state.weatherData.weather !== null &&
          this.state.weatherData.weather.map(obj => {
            return (
              <div key={obj.id}>
                {/* <span> */}
                id: {this.state.weatherData.weather[0].id}
                <br />
                main: {this.state.weatherData.weather[0].main}
                <br />
                discription: {this.state.weatherData.weather[0].description}
                <br />
                icon: {this.state.weatherData.weather[0].icon}
                {/* </span> */}
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WeatherData;
```

When I am trying to pass this component in the "renderToString" I am getting an empty value

I want to know how can I make this code get into the string along with the value which I am getting from the rest API.

NOTE: When I tried to pass the map component in the "renderToString" it was giving "Loading..." rather than the component with data. So I feel it is a timing issue.

I am trying to access this. And I am calling print in an onClick event handler.

```
const print = () => {
  const string = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<WeatherData />);
  const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");

  pdf.fromHTML(string);
  pdf.save("pdf");
};
```

Comment: `this.state.weatherData.weather` is undefined when call renderToString, later when the promise resolves the component would re render if was rendered to DOM but that's not what you do. According to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) you get the **initial** html, so componentDidMount will re set state but by then the initial html was already returned.

Comment: You see in the question. This is how I was trying to access it.

Comment: Instead of state provide the weather data as props. In the application you can use a container to do the asynchronous fetching and serer side you can fetch data first and then pass weather data as props to the component.

Comment: @HMR thank you, man, It works like a charm the way I want but In my big project I can not make the call outside of that component. So I still need to find a way to work with a component that makes the asynchronous call.

Comment: That is the problem when you combine presentational with container. You could make WeatherData a container (without jsx) and create a WeatherDataPresentational that WeatherData will render. On the server you don't use the WeatherData container that fetches the data and instead fetch the data yourself and then pass it to WeatherDataPresentational to get the html string.

Comment: Thank you this approach will help me a lote, There will be no duplicate code because of this. Thank you.